# How to get if checkbox is checked or not

Tags: javascript, php, html, checkbox

So I have to make [this soccer website](http://hyun.x10host.com/soccer/Register.html) where theres a list of checkboxes (i the registration) to select the prefered position. I want, for example, when someone inputs the center-attack checkbox and the goalie checkbox, to send me a list of the positions selected. As you can see, it's a picture with a  list of checkboxes fo every position

[image: The checkboxes layout]

So i used this code to see if the checkbox in question is selected (duplicated for every checkbox/position):

```
if (document.getElementById("goalie").checked == true) {
    var Goalie = "Goalie";
};
```

Then, I combine all the strings with:

```
PreferedPositions = Goalie + " " + LeftDefense + " " + CenterLeftDefense + " " + CenterRightDefense + " " + RightDefense + " " + LeftMidfield + " " + CenterMidfield + " " + rightmidfield + " " + LeftAttack + " " + CenterAttack + " " + RightAttack + ".";
```

And I send it to php so I can email it to the owner with ajax:

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "registration.php",
      data: {
            PostPreferedPositions: PreferedPositions
      },
success: function (res) {}
});
```

But when I test it out, the email comes out with:

"Prefered positions: undefined undefined undefined undefined undefined undefined undefined undefined undefined undefined undefined."

I understand all the undefined if I had selected none of the checkboxes. But this occurs no matter how many checkbox I have selected. Like if I had the goalie and center-attack selected, I would expect:

"Prefered positions: Goalie undefined undefined undefined undefined undefined undefined undefined undefined Center-Attack undefined."

But that's not the case. I know I can easily fix all the undefined by putting a else if in the statement, but I don't know why all the positions return as undefined.

Comment: You should `encodeURIComponent()` on it. But those vars look `undefined` to me.

Comment: Maybe because you declare Goalie variable inside if statement. That why PreferedPositions cannot read that variable. Try to declare Goalie variable outside if statement.

Comment: Really, these days everyone should be using [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append). Read the example. Oh, use with [XHR2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects).

Comment: @StackSlave  isn't it just a question of checking if a checkbox is checked and if it is, then I assign a string to the variable. It looks pretty error-less to me, so I don't know why the vars should be undefined. Also, I'm not sure I understand in what encodeURIComponent() would be useful for in this case (Barely used it so I don't know, but from what I know, it's only to encode strings).

Comment: After checking your rendered html source code on your site, none of your checkboxes have any id or name attributes.  So you'll need to give them a unique id or seek out the child input of your current id'ed element.  ...you should have posted your html in your question so that I didn't need to dig through your source code.

Comment: @Faiz Infy Actually, I call it from outside on my actual code, but I just put it inside here for simplicity sakes to not have this question be too long. Sorry for that, but yea that's what I always had and it's not working.

Comment: You should include relevant code. Not expect us to read through all of your web pages.

Comment: Are you sure the `IDs` are in the `inputs` and not in the `labels`?

Comment: @StackSlave @ mickmackusa You guys are right, I'm sorry I should of had the html in this question. I didn't because I tought I was sure the error was with the javascript. But turns out mickmackusa was right, I accidently put my id on the labels instead of the checkbox. After changing it, I can confirms it works.

Answer (score -1):

The variables are `undefined` due to the fact the variables don't exist as you only start declaring the variables when a checkbox is checked. However, I would advise to not declare single variables for each position. You might be better off by iterating through all the checkboxes on the page, quickly mocked up this (which might help): 
https://playcode.io/299838?tabs=console&script.js&output